# how open folder with multiple dataframes in python and merge into one csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, concatenation

## how open folder multiple df python in merge all in one csv file

#### I've around 700 csv files all have exacly the same columns, I need to merge all into one csv file.

### that is the data, it is all in one folder, there is a pattern in file name , it is like "date" = ex: 07 25 2018

```
07252018 = {name: "Carlos", age:"30", height: "15" }

name     age   height
Carlos   30    15



07262018 = {name: "Carlos", age:"30", height: "15" }

name     age   height
Carlos   30    15



and etc.. range of 700csv
```

#### what I done..

- it works, but is very manual, needs alot of typing, since there are 700 csv's

```
03012018 = pd.read_csv("Data/03012018 )
03022018 = pd.read_csv("Data/03012018 )
03032018 = pd.read_csv("Data/03012018 )
03042018 = pd.read_csv("Data/03012018 )
03052018 = pd.read_csv("Data/03012018 )
and etc..



file = pd.cancat([03012018,03022018,03032018,03042018,03052018 ])

file.to_csv("Data/file")
```

## Expected output will be a optimal way, to do it fast without alot of typing.

Comment: Are there some `csv` files that you don't need in that folder? i.e. will you append ALL of the csv's in your folder?

Comment: Yes, all the csv's in the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this should do:

## Option 1:

Less efficient, more readable:

```
def get_df():
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            aux=pd.read_csv(file)
            df=df.append(aux)
    return df
```

And then:

```
df=get_df()
```

## Option 2:

More memory efficient, less readable:

```
def df_generator():

    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            aux=pd.read_csv(file)
            yield aux
```

And then:

```
generator=df_generator()
df = pd.DataFrame()
for table in generator:
    df = df.append(table)
```

Note: for this to work as is, the script has to be INSIDE the folder with the csv's. Else, you'll need to add the relative path to that folder from the folder your script will be in.

Example: If your script is in the folder "Project" and inside that folder you have the folder "Tables" with all your csv's, you do:

```
os.listdir('Tables/')
```

Comment: ,thanks,  where do I put the path for the folder.

would you add a fake path in the example?

Comment: It'll work if the script is inside the folder. I'll add an example if the script is one folder above your csv folder

Comment: What's the purpose of the `df=pd.DataFrame()` in the generator?  Why is the generator version more 'efficient'?  Do timings confirm that?

Comment: With `numpy` arrays, it's more efficient to collect them in a list and apply `np.concatenate` once at the end.  List append is faster than repeated `np.append`.  I wonder if the same applies to `pd.concat` vs `df.append`?

Comment: `numpy`is even more efficient. The use of a generator is more memory efficient if the dataframes are big and there's memory constraints. Maybe I should have explained myself better. The `df=pd.DataFrame()` in the generator was leftover code from option 1, I'll fix that. Thanks @hpaulj